# Java screen session starting

Tags: linux, java

I am trying to launch a `sh` file wich starts a `screen` Session, but nothing happens.

When I try to launch it manually it works fine.

```
su minecraft -c "screen -S $1 -d -m sh start2.sh $2"
```

and in the `start2.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Dcom.mojang.eula.agree=true -jar /home/minecraft/network/versions/spigot-1.8.8.jar -p $1
done;
```

I try to launch it from Java with this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/minecraft/network/servers/" + info.getName() + "/start.sh", info.getName(), String.valueOf(info.getPort()));

Process p = pb.start();
```

Hope you can solve my problem.

Comment: You should add the error message. Without the error message, it's hard to help.